# What is the equilavent with this simple thread line of code in C# to task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I got confused in task class in c#. I want to know what is the equivalent line of my thread code of c# to task?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 3; 

        for (int x = 1; x <= i; x++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(RunThread);
            t.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void RunThread()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread..");
    }
```

Comment: I dont get your question. What exactly are you try to do?

Comment: I want to know what is the equivalent for this in using task class??

Comment: He wants that code written using the Task Parallel Library (TPL), I would guess.

Comment: Oh, I cant help you there, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
for (int x = 1; x <= i; x++)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(RunThread);
}
```

Comment: yes it works, can i calculate the time of it? I want to compare it with thread :)

Comment: It would be hard to count the time, since in both cases, the threads are started but not finished.

Comment: Alternatively, just take my word for it that Task will be faster in most cases, by managing the number of actual threads for you.

Comment: Task uses threads behind the scenes, but it manages the number of actual `Thread` objects required. I guarantee it will almost always do a better job of that than you or I will.